# Value return problem in function of python class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, recursion, depth-first-search

So I was working on a project and in that I have to find the best possible path ...so I used DFS for this now, the problem is that when in recursive call it prints all the possible outcomes and in the end the best one. But These values are not getting stored in the "PathList" variable list of class.

for example: The Graph.py is another file where the graphs are stored

```
import Graph

class G:
    def __init__(self,Graph,vis):
        self.graph = Graph
        self.dist=1000000
        self.PathList= []
        self.stack=[]
        self.visited=vis

    def addEdge(self, u,v):
        self.graph[u].append(v)

    def DFScall(self,v,f,dis):

        self.visited[v]=True
        self.stack.append(v)
        dis+=1
        if(v==f):
            if(dis<self.dist):
                self.PathList = self.stack
                self.dist=dis
                #print(self.PathList)
        else :
            for i in self.graph[v]:
                if self.visited[i] == False:
                    #print(self.visited[i])
                    self.DFScall(i,f,dis)

        self.stack.pop()
        self.visited[v]=False


    def DFS(self,v,f):

        self.DFScall(v,f,0)

    def returnPath(self):
        return self.PathList


if __name__== "__main__":
    graph=Graph.returnGraph()
    vis=Graph.returnNodes()
    g = G(graph,vis)
    g.DFS('S1','B8')

    Pathlist = g.returnPath()
    print(Pathlist)
```

And the output is:

```
['S1', 'F0', 'E1', 'D0', 'C1', 'C2', 'B3', 'B4', 'C5', 'D4', 'D3', 'E2', 'F3', 'G2', 'H3', 'I2', 'J3', 'J4', 'I5', 'H4', 'G5', 'F4', 'E5', 'E6', 'D7', 'C6', 'B7', 'B8']
['S1', 'F0', 'E1', 'D0', 'C1', 'C2', 'B3', 'B4', 'C5', 'D4', 'D3', 'E2', 'F3', 'G2', 'H3', 'H4', 'G5', 'F4', 'E5', 'E6', 'D7', 'C6', 'B7', 'B8']
['S1', 'F0', 'E1', 'D0', 'C1', 'C2', 'B3', 'B4', 'C5', 'D4', 'D3', 'E2', 'F3', 'F4', 'E5', 'E6', 'D7', 'C6', 'B7', 'B8']
['S1', 'F0', 'E1', 'D0', 'C1', 'C2', 'B3', 'B4', 'C5', 'D4', 'E5', 'E6', 'D7', 'C6', 'B7', 'B8']
['S1', 'F0', 'E1', 'D0', 'C1', 'C2', 'B3', 'B4', 'C5', 'C6', 'D7', 'D8', 'C9', 'B8']
['S1', 'F0', 'E1', 'D0', 'C1', 'C2', 'B3', 'B4', 'C5', 'C6', 'B7', 'B8']
['S1', 'F0', 'E1', 'E2', 'D3', 'D4', 'C5', 'C6', 'B7', 'B8']
[]
```

The last,list output is the output when called through main.....What should I do in this case and tell is if is there anything that I need to study .

Thank You

Comment: `self.PathList = self.stack` if you mean to copy then that's the wrong way to do it. Try: `self.PathList = self.stack[:]`

Comment: @BanishedBot ...Thank you very much It worked

Comment: Great! I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're not actually copying `stack` by doing

```
self.PathList = self.stack
```

Replace it with

```
self.PathList = self.stack[:]
```

or

```
self.PathList = list(self.stack)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not creating a copy of the best path. You should do:

```
self.PathList = self.stack.copy()
```

A full example (with PEP8 changes for readability):

```
import Graph


class GraphSearch:
    def __init__(self, graph, nodes):
        self.graph = graph.copy()
        self.nodes = nodes.copy()

        self.visited = None
        self.best_path_list = None
        self.current_path_list = None

    def reset_search(self):
        self.visited = {k: False for k, v in self.nodes.items()}
        self.best_path_list = list()
        self.current_path_list = list()

    def _dfs_call(self, current_node, end_node):

        self.visited[current_node] = True
        self.current_path_list.append(current_node)

        if(current_node == end_node):
            current_distance = len(self.current_path_list)
            best_distance = len(self.best_path_list)
            if(current_distance < best_distance):
                self.best_path_list = self.current_path_list.copy()
        else:
            for adj_node in self.graph[current_node]:
                if not self.visited[adj_node]:
                    self._dfs_call(adj_node, end_node)

        self.current_path_list.pop()
        self.visited[current_node] = False

    def dfs(self, current_node, end_node):
        self.reset_search()
        self._dfs_call(current_node, end_node)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    graph = Graph.return_graph()
    nodes = Graph.return_nodes()
    graph_search = GraphSearch(graph, nodes)
    start_node = 'S1'
    end_node = 'B8'
    graph_search.dfs(start_node, end_node)
    print(graph_search.best_path_list)
```

I have not tested the code since I do not have the test data.